# 'Message zoom' in pantheon-mail possible?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-mail

In freya with geary it was possible to zoom the message permanent with a '*user-message.css*' -file in */home/user/.config/geary*

Content

> body { zoom: 1.4; }

Now in loki it doesn't work anymore even if you create the file in
*/home/user/.config/pantheon-mail*

Some help or info here if this is still possible?

thx J.Ar